# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException generated when br.readLine() = ","

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

The code below has several functions which allow for things such as writing data to a document, reading it and putting the data in an array for a `JTable` later down the line.

```
package tabletest.populatetable;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class GetData {
    DataClass[] data = new DataClass[500];
    int nextPosition = 0;

    public GetData() {
        readData();
    }

    public void writeData()
    {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("resources/tabledata.txt")));

            for(int i=0; i < nextPosition; i++) {
                bw.write(data[i].toString());
                bw.newLine();
            }

            bw.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Data input");
        }
    }

    public void readData()
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/tabledata.txt")));
            String nextData = br.readLine();
            String[] arrayStringData;

            while (nextData != null) {

                try {
                    arrayStringData = nextData.split(",");
                } catch(NullPointerException nPE) {
                    arrayStringData = new String[] {" ", " "};
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < arrayStringData.length - 1; i++) {
                    if(arrayStringData[i] == null || arrayStringData[i] == "") {
                        arrayStringData[i] = " ";
                    }
                }

                DataClass getData = new DataClass();
                getData.col1 = arrayStringData[0].trim();
                getData.col2 = arrayStringData[1].trim();
                data[nextPosition] = getData;
                nextPosition++;
                nextData = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String[][] dataInTableForm() {
        final int colCount = 2;
        String[][] temp = new String[nextPosition][colCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < nextPosition; i++) {
            temp[i][0] = data[i].col1;
            temp[i][1] = data[i].col2;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private class DataClass {
        String col1;
        String col2;

        public String toString() {
            return col1 + ", " + col2;
        }
    }
}
```

The document which it is reading, `resources/tabledata.txt`, is 12 lines long and it looks like this.

```
asfias, adsnj
aw,aerfae
aw,aewaa
,tre
asfd, 
okfas,af
e,ds
sw,f
,
asfias, adsnj
aw,aerfae
aw,aewaa
```

The problem is on line 9 of the text document. This is where it is just a `,` on its own. When there is something before or after the comma this seems to work fine and I checked by removing the line to see if it definitely was the comma causing the problem.

When I looked at the console I discovered the problem was a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and the stack trace is below.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at tabletest.populatetable.GetData.readData(GetData.java:55)
    at tabletest.populatetable.GetData.<init>(GetData.java:14)
    at tabletest.Table.createTablePanel(Table.java:76)
    at tabletest.Table.createPanels(Table.java:34)
    at tabletest.Table.runGUI(Table.java:24)
    at tabletest.Table.main(Table.java:150)
```

Line 55 of the code is `getData.col1 = arrayStringData[0].trim();`

As you can see in the code I attempted several things to prevent this occurring but I have had no luck. I also tried removing the `.trim()` from the end of the line; however, exactly the same problem occurs.

I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem.

Comment: Surround line 54-58 with an `if (arrayStringData.length > 0)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javadoc of [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

So, `",".split(",")` will return an empty array, i.e. `new String[0]`.

If you want to keep trailing empty strings, use `",".split(",", -1)`, which will return `new String[] { "", "" }`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split` yanks the delimiter out of the resulting array. So, for a string with just "," your array would be of length 0 (the element at index 0 does not exist).

What you need to do is check whether the length is greater than 0. You can do this using the code `arrayStringData.length > 0` in an if statement before trying to access `arrayStringData`

Comment: Should the for loop or try catch block not prevent this?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it does catch it, but you're not doing anything with the Exception. You're just printing the stacktrace. What you need to do is check whether the length is greater than 0: `arrayStringData.length > 0` before trying to access it.

Comment: Sure is "yanks" the delimiter, but that is not why the result is an empty array, instead of an array of two empty strings. `","` is `"<emptyString>,<emptyString>"`, so reading that string as comma-separated values, it means two empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function will cut out the "," delimiter and return an empty array.

Your try-catch block is catching a null pointer exception if the `nextData` array is null, not if the output array is empty.

The for loop would only work if the output array contains null strings (which it doesn't).

Comment: It is true that `split()` never returns the delimiter, i.e "cuts it out", but that doesn't explain why it returns empty array, and not the expected array of two empty strings.